# Problem with QWeb reports rendering to PDF - style not getting

Tags: odoo, qweb

Having a hard time fixing my issue when rendering QWeb reports to PDF. Using the **/report/html** style is fine.

I need to push the TAX INVOICE # div to the very right side. Below is rendered from PDF

[Rendered in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZfAM.png)

In **/report/html** it is working fine.

[Rendered in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMhR0.png)

Using this style: `style="width: auto; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: auto;"` inside the div

```
<div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <table class="table table-sm o_main_table table-bordered" border="1">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center" colspan="2"><span>CUSTOMER</span></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-left"><span>SHIP TO:</span></th>
                                            <th class="text-left"><span>BILL TO:</span></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
                                        <tr t-att-class="'font-weight-bold o_line_section'">
                                            <td class="text-left"><span t-field="doc.partner_shipping_id.name" t-options="{'widget': 'text'}" /> <span t-field="doc.partner_shipping_id" t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": True}' /></td>
                                            <td class="text-left"><span t-field="doc.partner_id.name" t-options="{'widget': 'text'}" /> <span t-field="doc.partner_id" t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": True}' /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                            <div style="width: auto; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: auto;">
                                <table class="table table-sm o_main_table table-bordered" border="1" style="width: 100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center" colspan="2">
                                                <span>TAX INVOICE #</span>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr t-att-class="'font-weight-bold o_line_section text-center'">
                                            <td colspan="2"><h3 style="color: red;"><strong><span t-field="doc.name" t-options="{'widget': 'text'}"/></strong></h3></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try float instead. Set float to right for the second table (div) which contains tax invoice. It will work.